# Hypercorn server hooks

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, gunicorn, asgi, hypercorn

I have seen that gunicorn provide server hooks that we can use to hook on the various server event , I am looking for the same in hypercorn as it is inspired on gunicorn , but the hypercorn documentation is not of any help in this matter and i haven't found anyone implementing that .

hyperconr.config.py

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
print( (mp.cpu_count() * 2) + 1)

accesslog = "-"
backlog = 500
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
statsd_host = os.environ.get("STASD_HOST")
workers = 3
max_requests = 2
```

```
"""
This module is the entry point for the API.
This will contain all of the middleware and routes and database initialization
"""

from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.routing import Route

# from sample_project import HealthCheckAPI
from src.health_check import HealthCheckAPI

routes = [
    Route(f"/health-check", HealthCheckAPI)
]
app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=routes)
# app = AsyncioWSGIMiddleware(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from hypercorn.config import Config

    config = Config()
    config.bind = ["localhost:8077"]
    config.debug = True
    import asyncio

    from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

    asyncio.run(serve(app, config))
```

```
 hypercorn -c file:config/hypercorn.config.py  src.application:app
```

Below is the sample config for the gunicorn server with the server hook.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
print( (mp.cpu_count() * 2) + 1)

accesslog = "-"
backlog = 500
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
statsd_host = os.environ.get("STASD_HOST")
workers = 3
max_requests = 2

def on_starting(server):
    # register some variables here
    print(server)
    print("Starting Flask application")

def on_exit(server):
    # perform some clean up tasks here using variables from the application
    print("Shutting down Flask application")

def worker_exit(server, worker):
    print("Worker exiting")
    print(worker)

def nworkers_changed(server, new_value, old_value):
    print("n worker",new_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypercorn does not currently have any server hooks. However, on_starting and on_exit are accommodated for by the ASGI lifespan events. When using Starlette these are the on_startup and on_shutdown [events](https://www.starlette.io/events/).